# compute source code hash on pre-built ZIP file for lambda_module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have written a terraform module to create a Lambda and I'm having trouble figuring out how to compute the source_code_hash on a PRE-built ZIP file. This will be in a pipeline so the ZIP file will get built each time and perhaps be different before I reach the terraform step.
I'm building the ZIP file with gulp (this is a NodeJS App) and assume it is pre-built in directory 
build/myLambda.zip

Essentially I want to do this. The filename is a terraform variable and I want the source_code_hash computation has to reference that file.

```
module my_lambda {
  filename = "${var.my_zip_file}"
}
```

The relevant parts of the module are:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
   filename            = "${var.filename}"
   source_code_hash    = "${filebase64sha256(file("${var.filename}"))}"
}
```

However when I run terraform plan I get this error:

```
Error: Error in function call

  on modules\lambda\main.tf line 16, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda":
  16:     source_code_hash    = "${filebase64sha256(file("${var.filename}"))}"
    |----------------
    | var.filename is "build/myLambda.zip"

Call to function "file" failed: contents of
build/myLambda.zip are not valid UTF-8;
use the filebase64 function to obtain the Base64 encoded contents or the other
file functions (e.g. filemd5, filesha256) to obtain file hashing results
instead.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`filebase64sha256`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/filebase64sha256.html) function is similar to `base64sha256(file(...))`, but by combining the two functions together it avoids the need to create an intermediate string of the file contents and thus avoids the requirement that the file be UTF-8 encoded.

Therefore you don't need the `file` function call, because reading the file is built in to that function:

```
  source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256(var.filename)}"
```

Comment: With recent versions: `source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(var.filename)`